# Тело функции в аргументе

Tags: javascript

Я уже достаточно долго пишу на javascript, но до сих пор мне не ясны некоторые особенности языка.
Есть пример кода. В неё передается **тело** функции. Объясните пожалуйста на примере вашего кода как сделать так чтобы можно было передать **тело функции** в аргумент и как потом можно ее **вызвать**. Этот момент я уже достаточно долго не могу понять. Спасибо!

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('body');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передача функции как аргумент другой функции:

```
function someProcedure(callback) {
  var blaBlaBla = 5;
  callback(blaBlaBla * 10);
};
function iAmCallback(someNumber) {
  alert("someNumber is: " + someNumber);
};
someProcedure(iAmCallback);
```

Мы вызываем нашу процедуру `someProcedure` с аргументом функцией, которая будет вызван в качестве `callback` после определенных манипуляций.

Это лишь базовый пример, примерно таким образом чаще всего этот подход используется (посчитать что-то в одной функции, и вызвать функцию-аргумент с результатми подсчетов)

На всякий случай, уточню: функция-аргумент вызывается точно также, как и обычная функция, просто вы обращаетесь к ней как к переменной

Comment: Я сделал на основе вашего примера и у меня получилось. Спасибо за подробный рассказ! 
function func_main(callback) {
    callback();
}
func_main(function(){
    alert(100);
});

Comment: @Антон Если мой ответ - верный - приймите его, пожалуйста, как подходящий, нажав на галочку под стрелками